# Plesk, re-install "Parallels Premium Outgoing Antispam"

Tags: dspam

It's quite strange. Plesk autoinstall offers to install components but uninstall or re-install is not possible.

Right now i have problem starting "Parallels Premium Outgoing Antispam" which is installed and i have licence for. But i just get the message: "Protection : Not active. There are some problems that prevent the service from being started."

I really don't know what to do. I might be that i uninstalled it manually or in some other way few months before but i don't remember.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common bug in Plesk ~ 10.0.9. It has been fixed in Plesk 11.0.10 and will take effect during a fresh installation progress.

Your license key is installed in Parallels Plesk Panel, but it is **missing** from the configuration file of `Commtouch` [Outbound Spam Protection](http://www.commtouch.com/sp-outbound-spam-protection/) solution.

The resolution has been released as [**KB 115217**](http://kb.parallels.com/en/115217). Alternatively, you can reinstall the base package using Plesk Autoinstaller Utility, but this  is *not* a recommended way. Be aware!

Dump all databases like:

```
# mysqldump -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` --all-databases > /root/mysql.full.dump
```

Reinstall the base package:

```
# /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/autoinstaller --select-release-current --reinstall-component base
```